# Running Tomcat8 server Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: java, tomcat, server

Started a Tomcat server. It is running and listening on port 8080 as seen in the image but the page http://localhost:8080 doesn't load. No Error page is seen. Just a blank screen. What could be the issue?

After I had installed Tomcat8, I checked and I was able to access the index page. Since then I have added a Java Servlet class file in WEB-INF/classes/com/example/web.

See the image for more details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what link fails? but i believe that you fails in this, the tomcat index is 404 error the manager is in 8080/manager and the apps 8080/apps but 8080/ is 404 error

Comment: Sorry I could not follow